# Java: arithmetic with arrays (multiplication, addition, subtraction)

Tags: java, arrays

Below is a method I want to use to do calculations and return a value.  The equation is: L = T + R*p - b  where L, R, p, and b will have a subscript (0-5).  R is a 3x3 matrix, which is stored/generated in another class, p and b are arrays of 6 sets of (x,y,z) coordinates.  L should have 6 total values when the program runs, and I have chosen to store them in an array.

The first error I got was when I didn't have `rotationMultiply` or the `for` loops.  Instead I had `rotation*platformCoords`.  So now that I have gotten rid of that error, I get a new error "Syntax error on token "*", invalid AssignmentOperator" for the line `rotation[i][j]*platformCoords[i]` and another error, The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) double, double[], for line `tLength + rotationMultiply - baseCoords;`.

I'm sure there will be more errors once I get those taken care of, so if you can anticipate any and give me a heads up on where I can do some more learning I'd appreciate it.

This is one piece of a program I'm attempting to write that will help control a stewart platform.

```
public class LiCalc {

double length[];

public double legLength(double tLength, double[][] rotation, double[] platformCoords, double[] baseCoords ){

    double rotationMultiply;

      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
              rotation[i][j]*platformCoords[i];
              return rotationMultiply;
          }
      }    

    length = tLength + rotationMultiply - baseCoords;

    return length[];

}
```

}

Comment: Basically (a) You can't do an arithmetic operation without assigning it to *something*. That's why the first error occurs.  (b) You have to do arithmetic on scalar values, so you can't subtract a vector from a double, and `baseCoords` is basically a vector (an array). (c) What is `length[]`? And (d) how do you expect to assign the result of arithmetic (scalar!) to a vector?

Comment: So I definitely thought I was "assigning" the operation to `rotation[][]*platformCoords[]`, but everything youre saying makes me think I need to review the math, because I think `tLength` also needs to be a vector (I thought it would be a constant scalar value, but rereading this math makes me think differently).  `length[]` is the array of lengths each of the 6 legs on the platform needs to be.  Ultimately, another part of the program iterates through `length[]` does some calculations and outputs an angle that a specific servo needs to rotate.

Comment: You also need to review your Java. `length[]` is illegal if `length` is the name of a variable. An empty set of brackets is only legal after a Type name. And assignment is done with the `=` operator, or any of its short formats (`+=`,`/=` etc). You have to assign the *result* of an arithmetic operation to a scalar variable.

Comment: I derived the [Inverse Kinematics of Stewart Platforms](https://www.xarg.org/paper/inverse-kinematics-of-a-stewart-platform/). You case is the simple version of it, mentioned at the beginning of the derivation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is by no means mathematically 100% correct. I just corrected all obvious flaws and compiletime errors.

Try the following code and build the correct answer on it:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public final class LiCalc
{

    private LiCalc()
    {

    }

    public static double[] legLength(double tLength[], double[][] rotation, double[] platformCoords, double[] baseCoords)
    {

        double[] rotatedCoords = new double[platformCoords.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            double rotatedValue = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                rotatedValue += rotation[i][j] * platformCoords[i];
            }
            rotatedCoords[i] = rotatedValue;
        }

        double[] length = new double[platformCoords.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            length[i] = tLength[i] + rotatedCoords[i] - baseCoords[i];
        }

        return length;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(LiCalc.legLength(new double[]{1, 0, 0},
                new double[][] { { 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1 } }, new double[] { 0, 1, 1 }, new double[] { 1,
                        0, 0 })));
    }
}
```

Comment: So if you see my comment to @RealSkeptic, I think `tLength` needs to be an array also, and if I understand everything you've written, it shouldn't be a problem.  And just so I'm clear your `println` part of the code is just to check to see that what should have happened, did happen?

Comment: @WilliamB. The println part is just to check if i get an output at all. The answer is by no means correct. I just corrected all obvious flaws and compile errors. I did not check whether the Math is correct.